# Select last element with specific attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a select option structure like this

```
<option value="3" data-type="main"> Main Group 1 </option>
<option value="4" data-type="sub"> Sub Group 1 </option>
<option data-connectionid="1" value="1"> Item 1 </option>
<option value="3" data-type="main">Main Group 2 </option> // i want to get this
<option value="3" data-type="sub">Sub Group 2</option>
<option data-connectionid="2" value="2">Item 2</option>
```

I want to get the last option with data attribute `data-type="main"`, the options are dynamically generated.

Or if its possible what I want to start loop from the last option with `data-type="main"` up to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And for jQuery:

```
$("option[data-type='main']").last();
```

Comment: Ist possible to start loop from that option?

Comment: What do you want to loop over?

Comment: I got it thanks to you. I used .index() then .slice the options of the select using that index.

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('select > option[data-type="main"]')
console.log(el[el.length-1].innerHTML)
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j79vE/)